# Connecting to an SSL server with self-signed cert in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, ssl, as3crypto

Using [as3crypto's TLSSocket](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/tls/TLSSocket.as) it should be possible to connect to an SSL server. However, my server uses a self-signed certificate. How can I configure the client to accept that certificate?

I'm assuming I need to hard-code the cert's fingerprint in the client somewhere (or get it there some way). That's ok.

If as3crypto doesn't support this, other options are welcome.

Comment: Is everything in the same domain and being loaded from https?

Comment: No, not HTTPS, plain SSL/TLS, and the application will need to connect to several servers which may or may not be in the same domain (or have no domain name at all, just an IP address)